# Do I need to take care to pack vertex attributes together?

Tags: opengl, glsl

If I want to pass two nominally independent attribute arrays of floats to a draw call, can I happily have a GLSL `in float` variable for each of them, or do I need to ensure to pack them into an `in vec2` or similar and use the various components to ensure not consuming unnecessary `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` "slots"?

Or, in other words; `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` specifies, according to the docs, "the maximum number of 4-component generic vertex attributes accessible to a vertex shader". Does an attribute that is less than 4 components always count as one attribute towards this limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does an attribute that is less than 4 components always count as one attribute towards this limit?

Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Each vertex attribute is 4-component, if you write it as `float` in your shader that actually does not change anything. If you want to see this in action, try setting up a 1-component vertex attribute pointer and then declaring that attribute `vec4` in your vertex shader -- GL will automatically assign the values **0.0**, **0.0**, **1.0** for `y`, `z` and `w` respectively.

If you are hitting the vertex attribute limit (minimum 16) because you're using a bunch of scalars, then you should consider packing your attributes into a `vec4` instead for optimal utilization.

There is a minor exception to this rule I described above, for data types with more than 4-components (e.g. `mat4`). A vertex attribute declared `mat4` has 16-components and consumes 4 sequential attribute locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One would imagine that drivers could optimize around this restriction behind-the-scenes, though; are you aware if there is any particular reason why they don't?

Comment: @Dolda2000: GPUs have traditionally been designed around 4-component vectors and vector operations. These days GPUs are much more scalar friendly, but this sort of limitation even applies to uniforms on some older GPUs. GLSL defines a minimum number of uniform components a vertex shader needs to support, but some GPUs treat any uniform with fewer than 4-components as consuming 4-components -- from my understanding it is because they don't have scalar registers.

Comment: @Dolda2000: From the original [ARB Vertex Program specification](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/ARB/vertex_program.txt) (pre-dates GLSL): *"In order to define such vertex programs, this extension defines a vertex programming model including a floating-point 4-component vector instruction set and a relatively large set of floating-point 4-component registers."*